# edit specific things in a text document python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file contain some data using this piece of code

```
def Add_score():
    with open("users.txt") as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if name in line:
                line_found = num
                break
```

It finds the line that has a specific name. The line would look like this.

Name: whatever Username: whatever password: whatever score: 25

I would like to be able to add a number to the 25 within a file.

I do not know if it is possible.

But many thanks Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but should work.

```
def add_score():  # let me rename this to lowercase
    ans = []  # lets put the new file content here
    with open("users.txt") as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if name in line:
                line_found = num
                # break -- you don't want to break, you want your 25 to be 26
                *things, num = line.split(": ")  # extract whats after the last ': '
                things.append(int(num)+1)
                line = ": ".join(things)  # change the line
             ans.append(line)
    print("".join(ans), file=open("users.txt", mode='w'))
```